# Sql Query to return only items added this month

Tags: sql, sql-server

Im looking for a query that only returns new items for the month. i.e if this item was in last month exclude.

My table looks something like this

```
Date         fruit    buyer
2014-04-01   Apple    someone1
2014-04-01   Banana    someone2
2014-05-01   Apple    someone2
2014-05-01   Banana    someone2
2014-05-01   Pear    someone1
```

So in the case above I want a query that if run for 2014-05-01 would return only apple and pear because either the buyer or the fruit is distinct. but not banana because that exact record was in last month.

I have tried to use a not exists query on itself ie.

```
select Date, Fruit, buyer
from table
where date = 2014-05-01 and not exists(
select Date, Fruit, buyer
from table
where date = 2014-04-01)
```

But this seems to run for a long term and not return the correct results.

I also am aware that one solution would be to normalize buyer out but at the current time is not an option. (is for the long term)

This is on MSSQL.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You need to try something like this,  my apologies, for previous one, but idea is the same, you can visit this link for more

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb264565(v=sql.90).aspx

```
SELECT     EmployeeID, FirstName, LastName, HireDate, City
FROM       Employees
WHERE      (HireDate >= '1-june-1992') AND (HireDate <= '15-december-1993')
```

Comment: this is not what I am after. I want unique values. this I just selecting a date range

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by

```
select Date, Fruit, buyer
from table e
where date = 2014-05-01 
  and not exists(
    select Date, Fruit, buyer
    from table d
    where date = 2014-04-01 
      and e.buyer = d.buyer 
      and e.fuit = d.fruit)
```

Answer (score 0):

u need to exclude the buyer from your last month

```
SELECT DATE,FRUIT, BUYER FROM TABLE
WHERE FRUIT IN (
(
  Select Fruit
  from
  (
   SELECT FRUIT,BUYER FROM TABLE WHERE DATE = '2014-05-01'
   EXCEPT
   SELECT FRUIT,BUYER FROM TABLE WHERE DATE = '2014-04-01'
  ) T1
)

               )
AND DATE = '2014-05-01'
```

Answer (score 0):

I use inner join to create the query
try below query

Data:

```
xDate       fruit   buyer
----------------------------
2014-04-01  Apple   someone1
2014-04-01  Banana  someone2
2014-05-01  Apple   someone2
2014-05-01  Banana  someone2
```

Query:

```
select 
    convert(nvarchar(10),a.xdate,110),a.fruit, a.buyer
from 
    @temp a 
    inner join
    (
        select 
            b.fruit, b.buyer,b.fruit + ' ' + b.buyer as 'xField', count(*) as total
        from @temp b
        group by b.fruit, b.buyer, b.fruit + ' ' + b.buyer
        having 
        count(*) = 1
    ) c on a.fruit = c.fruit and a.buyer = c.buyer
where 
    a.xDate < dateadd(day,1,'20140630')
    --convert(nvarchar(6),a.xdate,112) = '201405'
```

Result:

```
            fruit   buyer
----------------------------
05-01-2014  Apple   someone2
05-01-2014  Pear    someone1
```

Note: 
If you need the Year in the where clause
add

```
DATEPART(Year, xdate) = 2014
DATEPART(Month,xdate) = 5
```

**UPDATED:**
if you do not want to use datepart func, you can use below where clause:

(format string 'YYYYMM')

```
convert(nvarchar(6),a.xdate,112) = '201405'
```

if we added this 2 records in the data:

```
2014-03-05 Apple    someone2
2014-03-10 Apple    someone1
```

Only pear will appear in the result data

```
05-01-2014  Pear    someone1
```

**2nd UPDATED**

To prevent NON-SARGable Query, the where clause is change to:

```
a.xDate < dateadd(day,1,'20140630')
```

Comment: Using a function (DATEPART) on a column renders is nonsargable, i.e. indexes can no longer be used, resulting in lousy performance.

Comment: thanks for the information, do you have a reference about this issue. i want to learn it further. thanks

Comment: See [What makes a SQL statement sargable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/799584/what-makes-a-sql-statement-sargable) - CONVERT is still nonsargable.  Use BETWEEN two DATE type parameters instead, or = a date type parameter.

Comment: thanks mate, great stuff. i got new things. i change it to xDate <='20140531'. is this ok?